# jquery: How to put webit reflection to animate in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reflection, webkit

I am able to use animate function in jquery to animate certain effect. But i wanted to do some reflective animation using webkit. How do i pass in the webkit css attribute?

```
$(this).animate({
     webkit-box-reflect:below 50px,
     top: y,
     left: x,
     height: photoSizes[1],
     width: photoSizes[0]
   },{
     duration: 1000,
     easing: 'easeOutBounce'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webkit-box-reflect:below 50px,` is wrong cause the `-` symbols are parsed as `minus`.

instead try with:

```
"webkit-box-reflect":"below 50px"
```

or also using camelCase:

```
boxReflect: "below 50px"
```

you can also use the CSS3 `transform` property like: `scaleY(-1)`

http://caniuse.com/#search=box-reflect